# Word for "ability to pick the right person"

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, idiom-request

Do you have an English word for "an ability to use people wisely"?

The meaning I would like to convey is the ability of someone who can pick the right person for the right job.  Failing that, is there a phrase or idiomatic expression which would equally do?

Comment: Are you looking for something like "wisdom" which is more general or "coach" which is more specific?

Comment: Can you write a sentence and put a blank (____)   where you want your word to go?

Comment: Having (an ability or skill to use the right people for the right job) is one of the ten qualities in being a leader.

Comment: There's also the expression the person who knows **the right man for the job** but that doesn't quite mean what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a single word, but in a business world, the term "[skills management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skills_management)" is broadly used which means:

> the practice of understanding, developing and deploying people and
>   their skills. Well-implemented skills management should identify the
>   skills that job roles require, the skills of individual employees, and
>   any gap between the two.

People have different skills, knowledge and aptitudes, etc and managing them effectively and efficiently are the key to success. A good manager must have excellent "management skills" or "management capability" and "skills management" is one of the most important management skills.